# How to get an accessToken using MSAL library inside a Sharepoint Web Part?

Tags: azure-ad

I have developed a Sharepoint Web Part where I need to obtain the accessToken. To obtain the token I have used a MSAL library.

My problem is the next one: I'm logged in my Sharepoint but when the Web Part try to retrieve the accessToken something fails in the authentication and appears this error:

```
xxxx-web-part.js:1838 ClientAuthError: User login is required.
at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxx-web-part.js:2057:28)
at new ClientAuthError (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:630:28)
at Function.7ZR7.ClientAuthError.createUserLoginRequiredError (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:682:16)
at https://localhost:4321/dist/xxx-web-part.js:2916:103
at new Promise ()
at UserAgentApplication.ZES5.UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:2905:16)
at UserAgentApplication.descriptor.value [as acquireTokenSilent] (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:2543:38)
at xxxWebPart.PlTk.xxxxWebPart.render (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:1828:19)
at xxxxWebPart.t._renderWithAccessibleTitle (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_27e01b6941bf5cdddecc695bd3bdbb95.js:21:585834)
at https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_27e01b6941bf5cdddecc695bd3bdbb95.js:21:585352
```

How can fix this problem?. I would like that if I'm logged in Sharepoint obtain the accessToken without relogin into the system.

This is my code:

```
export default class MyWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <IWebpartProps> {

    public render(): void {

    const config = {
     auth: {
        clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    }
};

const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(config);

    let accessTokenRequest = {
        scopes: ["user.read"]
    }

    myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
        // Acquire token silent success
        // call API with token
        let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
        let scopes = accessTokenResponse.scopes;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //Acquire token silent failure, and send an interactive request
        console.log(error);
        if (error.errorMessage.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1) {
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a workaround with something like this:

```
var accessTokenRequest = {
   scopes: ["user.read"],
   loginHint: preferred_username,
   extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}
}
```

Blessings and good night

Comment: Can yiu please provude what was the value you added to preferred_usernane? Im having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Type the SharePoint site URL in SiteURI. Type the User name and Password of the account, and click OK. The generated token appears in the Windows PowerShell window. Open the text file from the output specified in step 6, or copy the token text from the Windows PowerShell window.